# gcloud spark submit:Path does not exist: hdfs://cluster-xxxx-m/user/root/--;

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, airflow, gcloud, spark-submit

I am trying to use `gsutil` to submit my spark job from Airflow.

This is my `gcloud` command: `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster=xxx --region=us-central1 --class=com.xxx --jars=gs://xxx/xxx/xxx.jar -- xxx -- xxx -- xxx -- gs://xxx/xxx/xxx`

I am getting this exception: `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: hdfs://cluster-xxxx-m/user/root/--;`

Is anything wrong with my command?

Comment: If you have it enabled, try disabling the flat glob algorithm in the GCS connector by setting these Hadoop properties during cluster: `core:fs.gs.glob.flatlist.enable=false core:fs.gs.glob.concurrent.enable=false`.

Also upgrade the `GCS_CONNECTOR_VERSION` to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be solved by disabling the flat glob algorithm in the GCS connector, by setting these Hadoop properties during cluster creation `core:fs.gs.glob.flatlist.enable=false core:fs.gs.glob.concurrent.enable=false`. Additionally,  upgrade the `GCS_CONNECTOR_VERSION` to the latest with this command `--metadata GCS_CONNECTOR_VERSION=2.2.6`.